# Не работает модификация таблицы

Tags: postgresql, webstorm

Всем привет.
Я новичок в разработке базы данных.
На данный момент столкнулся с такими проблемами:

[image: Скрин с проблемой]


1) пытаюсь модифицировать таблицу - но добавляется почему то только 1 ряд постоянно.(а не 4 - как мне нужно.)
Что я делаю не так?

2) С права в редакторе есть графическая визуализация базы данных, в указанной стрелкой схеме есть таблица.
Но она почему то тут не отображается.
Можно ли это как то пофиксить?

P.S. Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: Может быть кто то посоветует другую графическую платформу(плагин для Webstorm) для postgresql - буду признателен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Это оказался глюк.
Плагин изначально не расчитат
(как я понимаю) на данную платформу(Webstorm)..